# Why is my Python code showing me "None" at this location?

Tags: python

So i shortened my code to make it easier to read

```
g = True

def welcome_message():
  print("welcome")

while g == True:
  g = False
  print(welcome_message())
  c = input("Do you understand ('yes' or 'no')")
  if c == "yes":
   print("okay")
  elif c == "no":
   g = True 
  else:
   print("That is not a valid input. Please try again.")
   g = True
```

However, when I run this code, I expect the code to print "welcome" and ask the person running the code if they understand. However, this is the result:

```
welcome
None
Do you understand ('yes' or 'no')
```

Why does my code show a "None" at that location?

Comment: Because you're printing what is returned from the function.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're printing the output of `welcome_message()`, and since the function never returns anything, it defaults to none.

To fix this, just don't print the function, and instead just call it with `welcome_message()`.

Comment: Oh god I'm so dumb, I put a "print" there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The line `print(welcome_message())` executes `welcome_message()` function and prints it's returned value. Since this function has no returned value, `None` is printed.

To avoid printing `None`, you can do:

```
def welcome_message():
  print("welcome")

while g == True:
  g = False
  welcome_message()
  c = input("Do you understand ('yes' or 'no')")
```

or

```
def welcome_message():
  return "welcome"

while g == True:
  g = False
  print(welcome_message())
  c = input("Do you understand ('yes' or 'no')")
```

Comment: Thanks I just realised my mistake

Answer (score 0):

First to correct the code you need to change the welcome function as below:

```
def welcome_message():
    return("welcome")
```

or to just call the `welcome_message()` without `print`

Why it gives you `None` is because of the type of object a print returns. Which is `<class 'NoneType'>` and your second `print` prints it like `print(None)`

Basically you we doing :

```
print(print("Welcome"))
```

The inner print shows the "Welcome" message and the outer print outputs `None` because of the result of inner print

Comment: I understand now! Thank you!